# using select loop vs fdisset

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to find out what is the difference between using a `select()` function and `FD_ISSET` call. What are the different scenarios that justify using either of them?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. You have to use both of them. You can't use one without the other.

Comment: I guess I was confused about what `FD_ISSET` exactly does and hence posted this question. Thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select() function indicates which of the specified file descriptors is ready for reading, ready for writing, or has an error condition pending.

FD_ISSET() tests to see if a file descriptor is part of the set; this is useful after select() returns.

Answer (score 1):

An `fd_set` is a bit array used as input in calls to `select`.

`FD_ISSET` is used to check whether a specific bit is set in an `fd_set`.

`select` is used to poll all file descriptors that correspond to bit that are set in an `fd_set`.

A typical scenario will be to:

Create and clear an `fd_set`.

Set bits for the file descriptors you want to monitor.

Call select.

Call `FD_ISSET` in a for loop. If a particular bit is set, that file descriptor is ready to be read (or written or has an error).

Answer (score 0):

`select` is a system call and application programming interface in Unix like operating systems for examining the status of file descriptors of open input/output channels. Thus the `select()` function indicates which of the specified file descriptors is ready for reading, ready for writing, or has an error condition pending.

`FD_ISSET` returns a value for the file descriptor in the file descriptor set. It is declared in the header file `<sys/time.h>`. 
The prototype is,

```
int FD_ISSET(int fd, fd_set* fdset)
```

It returns a non-zero value if the file descriptor is set in the file descriptor set pointed to by `fdset`, otherwise returns 0.